# How to run part of r script until error is gone

Tags: r

I cannot load some packages in R in one-go, so need to repeat it multiple time. So I need to load all these packages until they are completely loaded. Is there a way I can program it for repeated loading until they all are successfully loaded?

```
    library(biomaRt)
    library(dplyr)
    library(stringi)
    library(GenomicFeatures)
    library(Rsamtools)
    library(foreach)
    library(doMC)
    library(doMC)
```

Comment: Why are they not available in one go?  You might want to try to solve that.

Comment: @tmthydvnprt I am not sure why and may be that is cluster thing. I have to `
source ~/.bashrc` to source the library in my home directory. Then I have to run the `library()` command multiple times to load some packages. I have no issue when I do it in my local machine.

Comment: You can probably do `while (!require(doMC) {require(doMC)})`. Pretty weird though.

Comment: I don't speak `R`, came here via review.  But I upvoted so maybe it'll get more attention.

Comment: This is the problem I am having: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36145197/force-load-r-packages-while-running-the-job-in-cluster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a cool way:

The **try()** function in R proceeds to execute a script if an error is thrown. The **library()** function loads a package, and throws an error if it is unsuccessful.

Basically, I set up a **while** loop that tries to reload the packages every five seconds until they have all been loaded successfully. I added some nice diagnostic messages.

```
myPackages <- c("ggplot2", "stats", "zoo")
tryCount <- 0    

while( !all(myPackages %in% (.packages())) ){

  try(library(ggplot2))
  try(library(stats))
  try(library(zoo))

  tryCount <- tryCount + 1

  if( !all(myPackages %in% (.packages()))  ){
    cat(paste0("Failure: ", tryCount, "\n"))
    cat("Failed to load: ")
    cat(myPackages[ !myPackages %in% (.packages()) ])
    cat("\n")
  } else {
    print(paste0("Success!"))
  }

  Sys.sleep(5)

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is a cool way to subdue this problem. It worked for me.

Comment: You're right @jenesaisquoi either could be used in this script. I edited to use library for clarity.

Comment: The try prevents the script from failing over. The OP wants to retry after some time if the package failed to load. Without try(), R would throw an error and quit out of the while loop.